# can't load data from Grid to new Window with Form Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, extjs

i'm having an issue loading data from a grid to a form in Extjs 4.

I'm trying to send the field vid to the form, just for testing but I can't even do that. Found lots of examples, tried the ideas. can't do it.

The data comes from mongodb.

I can show it in a grid perfectly.

And now I want to click in the Edit Button to open a window with a form and show the information.

What am I missing?

```
Ext.define('DevJS.view.users.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    autoHeight: true,
    forceFit: true,
     this.columns = [
                {text: 'Id', dataIndex: '_id', hidden: true},
                {
                    text: 'Vid',
                    dataIndex: 'vid',
                    autoSizeColumn: true

                }
    ...
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                        autoSizeColumn: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                iconCls: 'button-edit',
                                tooltip: 'Edit',
                                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                                    this.up('grid').fireEvent('editRow', grid, rowIndex, colIndex);
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                iconCls: 'button-info',
                                itemId: 'Comments',
                                text: 'Comments',
                                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, item) {
                                    alert(rowIndex)
                                    win.record = rowIndex;

                                    win.show()
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ];

                //parent
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        });

        var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            title : 'Test form',
            id:'form',
            width : 300,
            items : [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                editable:false,
                fieldLabel: 'vid',
                name: 'vid'
            }]
        });

        var win = new Ext.Window({
            title : 'test',
            items : [{
                xtype : 'panel',
                layout : 'column',
                items : [form]
            }],
            listeners:{
                afterrender:function(window) {
                    if(window.record) window.down('form').loadRecord(window.record);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the window, it is rendered (the DOM is built somewhere in the background) but `window.record` is not yet set.

But after the handler sets `win.record`, the window is not rerendered, only shown.

So it should work if you switch from the `afterrender` to `beforeshow` event, which is executed every time `win.show()` is called.

Furthermore, `window.record` contains the index of the record, not the record itself; but [`loadRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord) takes a record, not an index. Try sth like `win.record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);` and loadRecord` should be able to load the record.

Comment: Did It, didn't work. Do I need to do something at the form side? to map the data.

Comment: I had a closer look at your code and have to admit that I overlooked another error. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

just try this at after render method :

```
if(window.record) window.down('form').getForm().loadRecord(window.record);
```

hope it works.

Comment: didn't but thanks for the help. will try other ways using this advice